# How to understand php errors from dmesg

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, memcached

I get a blank page and a new entry in dmesg for every single request.

```
php[41369] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fff281f0d98 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
php[41399] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fffad17fd68 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
php[41408] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fff84481ce8 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
php[41412] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fff56af32f8 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
php[41417] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fff1e4d1ca8 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
php[41426] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fff87a67108 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
php[41431] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fffb16bacc8 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
php[41437] general protection ip:5c0cc3 sp:7fffbc41d5c8 error:0 in php[400000+33c000]
```

I've already found that it's caused by php-memcache. When switching my caching driver to anything but memcached it seems to work properly (I've tested file and array => no caching). But as I want memcached I am wondering how can I investigate further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to understand php errors from dmesg

It's pretty simple: it tells you that `php` binary was mapped at address range `[0x400000, 0x400000+33c000)` (normal for `x86_64` binaries on Linux), and that various processes (pid `41369`, `41399`, etc.) crashed with register `rip` (aka program counter) set to `0x5c0cc3`, and register `rsp` (aka stack pointer) set to various values (stack is randomized on Linux).

Since all `rip` values are the same, the crash is happening in the exact same place in all instances.

> how can I investigate further?

You need to install debug symbols for this `php` build.

Once you do, you can first determine which function the crash is happening in, like so:

```
gdb /path/to/php
(gdb) x/i 0x5c0cc3   # GDB will tell you instruction and function
```

Once you know the function, you could google for a solution or a known bug.

You could also attach GDB to a running `php` process, then issue a request. If your `php` crashes, you will now be able to see the call stack that lead to the crash with `(gdb) where` command.

Beyond that, you can build the `php` packages from source, with optimization disabled, and do source debugging.

All of this assumes that you know how to compile packages, how to debug `C` code, etc. If you don't know that, you'll have to enlist someone who does.